# KeyValuePair Take n number of results per distinct value

Tags: c#

I have a `KeyValuePair` which returns all results. I need to take `n` number of records per value.

So if I have 'Harry' and 'Sally', I need Harry to be listed 5 numbers of time and Sally 5 number of times

I currently have this:

```
var organiser = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
foreach(someinfo)
{
   organiser.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", Name));
}
foreach (var p in organiser.GroupBy(KeyValuePair =>KeyValuePair.Value))
{
   <p>@p.Key</p>
}
```

But this just returns Harry and Sally, I cannot work out have to add the `take()` to the code.

How can I do this?

Comment: A question, though. Why use a list of KeyValuePairs when you can use a Dictionary? If anything, you can use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, which incidentally comes with the names pre-grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some Linq, Group by the Key and then Take 5:

```
var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Harry", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Harry", "2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Harry", "3"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Harry", "4"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Harry", "5"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Harry", "6"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Harry", "7"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Sally", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Sally", "2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Sally", "3"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Sally", "4"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Sally", "5"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Sally", "6"),
};


var output = data.GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Take(5));

foreach (var item in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {item.Key}, Value: {item.Value}");
}
```

The output will be

```
Key: Harry, Value: 1
Key: Harry, Value: 2
Key: Harry, Value: 3
Key: Harry, Value: 4
Key: Harry, Value: 5
Key: Sally, Value: 1
Key: Sally, Value: 2
Key: Sally, Value: 3
Key: Sally, Value: 4
Key: Sally, Value: 5
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin Smith